# WCF streaming service

Tags: wcf, service, real-time

I want to display some real-time data in a chart, in a WPF client. The data should come from a WCF service. Right now, it works with a basic WCF service (wsHttpBinding), but it doesn't fulfill my need of real-time plotting. I call the service asynchronously, then update my UI, but I need to eliminate the time of waiting for the service call to finish.

I want to be able to read a value from the service stream every 40 miliseconds, and update  my chart. Which is the best way to do this using WCF?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an absolute requirement of 40 millisecond old data then WCF may not be the correct choice. WCF protects you from the plumbing, but that comes at a cost. You can get better performance using sockets directly.

For an example of how to use streaming in WCF see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Also Infragistics have some WPF controls for showing realtime data. See: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/data-visualization.aspx#Overview

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. What I want to display is really an ECG signal. I think those 40 miliseconds (the smallest unit you see on a printed ECG) can increase a bit, like say 500 miliseconds or more. What I want is for the signal to be displayed continously, in a smooth way, just like you see it on a medical ECG device. So my question is..what's the boundary where WCF streaming is no longer an option and I should use sockets? Also, thanks for the Infragistics tip, but buying 3rd party controls is not an option. I currently use Dynamic Data Display for the chart control.

Answer (score 0):

do you have some code what you have so far?

i would simply open a duplexclient proxy and listen to the wcf service callbacks. but to be honest, i dont know how fast it is.

Comment: I'll try the duplex solution and see how it performs. I didn't want to waste time on something that maybe it isn't even worth considering.